# Handle X-axis label position in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Please look into this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mxhogmd/5/)

If you resize the output window you will notice that the labels of x-axis becomes slanted. which is fine for me. But if you notice that the end position of label is center of bar. I want the end position of label to be the right-side end of bar. How can achieve this?

My config is

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["2 Jan", "9 Jan", "16 Jan", "23 Jan", "30 Jan", "6 Feb", "13 Feb"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [6, 87, 56, 15, 88, 60, 12],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            "display": false
        },
        tooltips: {
            "enabled": false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: false,
                gridLines: {
                    display : false
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: false,
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display : false
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is certainly possible to achieve a 'right' aligned scale tick label instead of the original 'center' aligned scale tick label, but unfortunately it is not very straight forward to implement.  Let me walk you through how to do it and then provide an example.

1) First, since there is no configuration option to control this, we have to look at doing some sort of custom implementation.  It turns out that the scale tick labels in a bar chart are rendered as part of the `Category` scale's draw method.  Therefore, we must somehow overwrite this `draw` method to change to a new alignment.

2) According to the [API](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-scale-types) there is a documented way to create new scale types, so we should be able to use a similar approach to extend the `Category` scale type and overwrite it's `draw` method.

Since all scales are wrapped up in the `ScaleService` we have to use the below approach to extend an existing scale type.

```
var CategoryRightAligned = Chart.scaleService.getScaleConstructor('category').extend({});
```

3) Now its just a matter of figuring out what part of the `draw` method we need to modify.  After looking it over, it looks like we need to change the logic for calculating `labelX` (the pixel position to render the tick label).  Here would be the new logic.

```
// current logic for getting pixel value of each label (we will use the logic below to 
// adjust if necessary)
labelX = me.getPixelForTick(index, gridLines.offsetGridLines) + optionTicks.labelOffset;

// get a reference to the bar chart controller so we can determine the chart's bar width
var meta = me.chart.getDatasetMeta(0);

// use the bart chart controller to calculate the bar width
var barWidth = meta.controller.calculateBarWidth(meta.controller.getRuler());

// if the labels are rotated, then move the pixel location from the middle of the bar 
// to the far right of the bar
if (labelRotationRadians != 0) {
  labelX += barWidth / 2;
}
```

4) Now we just need to register our new scale and configure the chart to use it (instead of the bar chart default category scale).

```
Chart.scaleService.registerScaleType('categoryRightAligned', CategoryRightAligned, {position: 'bottom'});

xAxes: [{
  type: 'categoryRightAligned',
  gridLines: {
    display : false,
    offsetGridLines: true
  },
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero:true,
  }
}]
```

Refer to this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordanwillis/06g7f132/2/) example to see it in action and to see how everything fits together.

Comment: the jsfiddle appears to no longer work? just shows the same center alignment for both graphs

Comment: In this example, the right alignment of the x-axis labels only occurs when the labels are too small to fit horizontally and get auto-rotated.  You should be able to shrink the width of the JSFiddle output window so that's its fairly small in order to trigger the rotation and see the difference.